# What mean of this

Tags: meaning

I am reading a matt's iOS book, when I read here, I have two place do not understand.

> For a view’s underlying layer, layoutSublayers or layoutSublayers(of:) is called after the view’s layoutSubviews. Under autolayout, you must call super or else autolayout will break. Moreover, these methods may be called more than once during the course of autolayout; if you’re looking for an automatically generated signal that it’s time to do manual layout of sublayers, a view layout event might be a better choice.

1. "you must call super or else autolayout will break", this phrase I can't understand.
2. "if you’re looking for an automatically generated signal that it’s time to do manual layout of sublayers"

What mean of the two place?

Comment: "call super" probably means "invoke the equivalent superclass method". See [*What exactly is super in Objective-C?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095360/what-exactly-is-super-in-objective-c)

Comment: I'm guessing that "that it’s time to do" should read ", then it's time to do".

Comment: @Mick, I know the `super` meaning, but I don't understand the `must call super ` mean, and `else autolayout will break` , does it mean, if do not call super , the autolayout will not work? and if this, call super waht?

Comment: I'm guessing, since I don't know iOS programming, but it may mean that you should invoke the superclass method before you do anything in your own method. You should probably ask this on [*Stack Overflow*](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: What mean of the two? Please.

Answer (score 1):

> "you must call super or else autolayout will break"

You must invoke the superclass constructor or the autolayout will not work.  I have no idea why this is, or why it breaks formatting.

> "if you’re looking for an automatically generated signal that it’s time to do manual layout of sublayers,  a view layout event might be a better choice."

If you want an event to fire when it's time to invoke your method that manually lays out sublayers, you should use a "view layout event" (presumably instead of autolayout).

Again, no idea what he's talking about, but that's what it seems to mean.  It's not very well-written, and certainly even more incomprehensible without the complete context.